# Can't use sub-document fields in Spring data mongodb $graphLookup

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

The documents in the collection **test_links** looks:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "57:58", 
    "from" : {
    "orgunitType" : "Regional", 
    "refId" : "57", 
    "name" : "Root Node"
}, 
    "to" : {
    "orgunitType" : "Department", 
    "refId" : "58", 
    "name" : "Department1"
}, 
"active" : true, 
}
```

While trying to implement a MongoDB aggregation query:

```
db.test_links.aggregate([
        {$match: {"to.refId":"64"}},
        {$graphLookup:{
             from: "test_links",
             startWith: "$to.refId",
             connectFromField: "from.refId",
             connectToField: "to.refId",
             as: "parents"
        }}]);
```

As Spring Data MongoDB:

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(match(where("to.refId").is(id)),
    graphLookup("test_links").startWith("$to.refId").connectFrom("from.refId")
        .connectTo("to.refId").as("parent")
);
AggregationResults results = infraTemplate.aggregate(agg, "test_links", Map.class);
```

The **connectFrom** and **connectTo** field values (from.refId, to.refId) replaced with *refId* ("from" and "to" stripped). As a result, query doesn't return any results.
Constructor of **AggregationField** class keeps original name in *target* field and set *name* stripped ("refId").
The problem is that **GraphLookupOperation.toDocument** method uses *field.getName()* instead of *field.getTarget()*:

```
...
graphLookup.put("connectFromField", connectFrom.getName()); 
graphLookup.put("connectToField", connectTo.getName());
...
```

Is there a workaround? And will it be fixed in future versions?
I understand that I can create my own **CustomAggregationOperation**, but it will be nice to use things out-of-box feature, if somebody tried to develop it.

**Spring Data MongoDB version 2.0.0.M4**

Answer (score 2):

In `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb\1.5.4.RELEASE` same behaviour, not sure is it expected to be such, but I found workaround.

Problem with `connectToField: "to.refId"` is that here used embedded value, by providing full path to that field all works fine, as expected, so should be changed to: `connectToField: "COLLECTION_NAME.to.refId"`